# In Hebrews 1:9 what is the "oil of gladness"?

Tags: hebrews

What is "happiness oil"? Does it make you happy? Or is happiness the oil?

> Heb 1:8  But unto the Son he saith, Thy throne, O God, is for ever and
>   ever: a sceptre of righteousness is the sceptre of thy kingdom.  Heb
>   1:9  Thou hast loved righteousness, and hated iniquity; therefore God,
>   even thy God, hath anointed thee with **the oil of gladness** above thy
>   fellows.
>
> Heb 1:8  προς δε τον υιον ο θρονος σου ο θεος εις τον αιωνα του αιωνος
>   Aκαι ραβδος ευθυτητος η Aραβδος Aτης Aευθυτητος ραβδος της βασιλειας
>   σου  Heb 1:9  ηγαπησας δικαιοσυνην και εμισησας ανομιαν δια τουτο
>   εχρισεν σε ο θεος ο θεος σου **ελαιον αγαλλιασεως** παρα τους μετοχους
>   σου

Comment: I think maybe there is a missing emphasis on examining what "[Oil, (שָׁ֫מֶן definition)](http://biblehub.com/hebrew/8081.htm)" actually represents, (in addition to "Joy" and "word order").  Specifically, perhaps "Oil" should be understood in its most literal and vulgar sense, "***Fatness***, and Excess".  ***Excessive Joy***.  Like being "anointed with the oil of the Holy Spirit", ***Excessive indwelling***.  Both ***"Joy Grease"*** and ***"Grease of Joy"*** are valid word ordering : ***"Excess of Joy"*** or ***"Joy Excess"***.

Answer (score 1):

Hebrews 1:8-9 is directly quoting the Septuagint version of Psalm 45:6-7:

> **Psalm 44:6-7 LXX**
>
> > **ὁ θρόνος σου, ὁ θεός, εἰς αἰῶνα αἰῶνος, 
> >           ῥάβδος εὐθύτητος ἡ ῥάβδος τῆς βασιλείας σου. 
> >           ἠγάπησας δικαιοσύνην καὶ ἐμίσησας ἀνομίαν· 
> >           διὰ τοῦτο ἔχρισέν σε ὁ θεός, ὁ θεός σου, 
> >           ἔλαιον ἀγαλλιάσεως παρὰ τοὺς μετόχους σου.**
> >
> > *Thy throne, O God, is for ever and ever: the sceptre of thy kingdom is a sceptre of righteousness, Thou hast loved righteousness, and
> >     hated iniquity: therefore God, thy God, has anointed thee with the oil
> >     of gladness beyond thy fellows.*<sup>1</sup>
>
> **Hebrews 1:8–9**
>
> > πρὸς δὲ τὸν υἱόν·
> >  **ὁ θρόνος σου, ὁ Θεός, εἰς τὸν αἰῶνα τοῦ αἰῶνος·
> >     ῥάβδος εὐθύτητος ἡ ῥάβδος τῆς βασιλείας σου. ἠγάπησας δικαιοσύνην καὶ
> >     ἐμίσησας ἀνομίαν· διὰ τοῦτο ἔχρισέ σε, ὁ Θεός, ὁ Θεός σου ἔλαιον
> >     ἀγαλλιάσεως παρὰ τοὺς μετόχους σου·**
> >
> > *But unto the Son he saith, Thy throne, O God, is for ever and ever: a sceptre of righteousness is the sceptre of thy kingdom. Thou hast
> >     loved righteousness, and hated iniquity; therefore God, even thy God,
> >     hath anointed thee with the oil of gladness above thy
> >     fellows.*<sup>2</sup>

Paul is providing a Christological interpretation of the Psalm, relating it to the anointing of Christ - which in Greek (*Christos*) means *the anointed one* - as King.  *Gladness* is associated here because the Psalm itself is a commemoration of a wedding, wherein neither the king nor queen are named.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sup>Brenton translation</sup>
<sup>2</sup>  <sup>King James Version (1900) translation</sup>

Comment: In Hebrew, it's Psalms 45:7 - Oil of Gladness "שמן ששון", **[Hebrew, at Biblehub.com](http://biblehub.com/text/psalms/45-7.htm)**.  Also, [Isaiah 61:3](http://biblehub.com/interlinear/isaiah/61-3.htm).  **Perhaps, [Oil | שָׁ֫מֶן](http://biblehub.com/hebrew/8081.htm)** should be understood in the most literal sense - ***fatness***, excess, lavishness, and choicest, (as in the [USDA's grading of Beef](http://www.primesteakhouses.com/how-usda-grades-beef.html) - Prime, Choice, Select).  That is, ***an abundant excess of joy***.